# Eliminate column duplicacy in jsp and using javascript

Tags: javascript, database, jsp, drop-down-menu

i have 5 JSP pages that r used to create 4 dependent drop downs and at the selection of last drop down a table is displayed
the code is as follows:
1st page:index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
  <html>
  <head>  
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
      var xmlHttp  
      var xmlHttp
  var global
  var state
  var district
      function showState(str){
  global=str;
      if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
      xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
  xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (xmlHttp==null){
  alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
  return;
  } 
  var url="state.jsp";
  url +="?count=" +str;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);

  }

  function stateChange(){   
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
  document.getElementById("state").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
  }   
  }
  function showCity(str){
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
    xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  if (xmlHttp==null){
  alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
  return;
  } 
  var url="city.jsp";
  state=str;
  url +="?count=" +str + " " + global;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange1;
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
  function stateChange1(){   
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
  document.getElementById("city").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
  }   
  }
  function showBank(str1){
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
    xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  if (xmlHttp==null){
  alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
  return;
  } 
  var url="bank.jsp";
  district=str1;
  url +="?count=" +str1;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange2;
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
  function stateChange2(){   
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
  document.getElementById("bank").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
  }   
  }
  function showPage(str2){
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
    xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
    xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  if (xmlHttp==null){
  alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
  return;
  } 
  var url="table.jsp";
  url +="?count=" +str2 + " " + state + " " + district;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange5;
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  }
  function stateChange5(){   
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
  document.getElementById("bank").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
  }   
  }

  </script>  
  </head>  
  <body> 

  <select name='country' onChange="showState(this.value)" style="top:150px; position:absolute;">

   <option value="none">&nbsp;DBTL Phase&nbsp;</option>  

  <%
 java.sql.Connection con;
con=null;
{
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con =     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
  }
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select DISTINCT DBTLdist from districts ORDER BY DBTLdist ASC");
 while(rs.next()){
 %>
  <option><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>  
  <%
 }
 %>
  </select>  

  <div id='state'>  

  <select name='state' style="left:200px; top:150px; position:absolute;"> 

   <option value="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;States&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option> 

  <option value='-1'></option> 

  </select>  
  </div>  

  <div id='city' >  

  <select name='city' style="left:400px; top:150px; position:absolute;">  
   <option value="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Districts&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
  <option value='-1'></option>  
  </select>  
  </div>
 <div id='bank' >  

  <select name='bank' style="left:600px; top:150px; position:absolute;">  
   <option value="none">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Banks&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
  <option value='-1'></option>  
  </select>  
  </div>






  </body> 
  </html>
```

2nd page:state.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%
String phase=request.getParameter("count");
out.println(phase);

String buffer="<select name='state' style='left:200px; top:150px; position:absolute;'s     onchange='showCity(this.value);'><option value='-1'>Select</option><option>All</option>";  

try{
if(phase.equals("none"))
{
java.sql.Connection con;
con=null;
{
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
  }
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from states ORDER BY State_Long ASC ");  
  while(rs.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(3)+"</option>";  
   }  
   }
   else
   {
 java.sql.Connection con;
con=null;
{
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
  }
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from states where State_Code IN (select     State_Code from districts where DBTLdist='"+phase+"') ORDER BY State_Long ASC ");  
   while(rs.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(3)+"</option>";  
   }  
  }
 buffer=buffer+"</select>";  
 response.getWriter().println(buffer); 
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
 }
%>
```

3rd page :city.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
 <%@page import="java.util.*"%>

<%
String state=request.getParameter("count");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(state," ");
   String s1=st.nextToken();
      String s2=st.nextToken();

String buffer="<select name='city' style='left:400px; top:150px; position:absolute;' onChange='showBank(this.value);'><option value='-1'>Select</option><option>All</option>";  
try{

  if(s1.equals("All"))
  {
  java.sql.Connection con;
con=null;
{
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con =     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
  }
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(" select * from districts where DBTLdist='"+s2+"' ORDER BY District_Name ASC");  
   while(rs.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(2)+"</option>";  
   }  
   }
   else if(s2.equals("null") || s2.equals("none"))
   {
   java.sql.Connection con21;
con21=null;
{
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con21 =     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
  }
   Statement stmt21 = con21.createStatement();  
 ResultSet rs21 = stmt21.executeQuery(" select * from districts where State_Code='"+s1+"' ORDER BY District_Name ASC");  
   while(rs21.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs21.getString(1)+"'>"+rs21.getString(2)+"    </option>";  
   }
   }
   else
   {
   java.sql.Connection con2;
con2=null;
{
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
   con2 = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
  }
   Statement stmt2 = con2.createStatement();  
 ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery(" select * from districts where DBTLdist='"+s2+"' AND State_Code='"+s1+"' ORDER BY District_Name ASC");  
   while(rs2.next()){
    buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs2.getString(1)+"'>"+rs2.getString(2)+"</option>";  
   }
   }
  buffer=buffer+"</select>";  
  response.getWriter().println(buffer);


  }
 catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
 }
  %>
```

4th page:bank.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%
String district=request.getParameter("count");
out.println(district);
String buffer="<select name='bank' style='left:600px; top:150px; position:absolute;'      onChange='showPage(this.value);'><option value='-1'>Bank</option><option>All</option>";  

try
{
if(district.equals("All"))
{
java.sql.Connection con1;
con1=null;
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con1 = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
 Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement(); 
  ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("select * from banks ORDER BY bank_name ASC");  
   while(rs1.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs1.getString(1)+"'>"+rs1.getString(2)+"</option>";  
   }  
   }
   else
   {
java.sql.Connection con;
 con=null;
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select DISTINCT * from banks where bank_code IN (select bank_code from bankdetail where district_code='"+district+"') ORDER BY bank_name ASC");  
   while(rs.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(2)+"</option>";  
    }  
   }
 buffer=buffer+"</select>";  
 response.getWriter().println(buffer); 
}
catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
 }

%>
```

5th page : table.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
String bank=request.getParameter("count");

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(bank," ");
   String bank_code=st.nextToken();
      String state=st.nextToken();
         String district=st.nextToken();
 String buffer="<select name='bank' style='left:600px; top:150px; position:absolute;' onChange='showPage(this.value);'><option value='-1'>Bank</option><option>All</option>";  

   try
    {
    if(district.equals("All"))
{
java.sql.Connection con1;
con1=null;
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con1 =     java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
 Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement(); 
  ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("select * from banks ORDER BY bank_name ASC");  
   while(rs1.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs1.getString(1)+"'>"+rs1.getString(2)+"</option>";  
    }  
    }
   else
   {
 java.sql.Connection con;
 con=null;
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
   con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select DISTINCT * from banks where bank_code IN (select bank_code from bankdetail where district_code='"+district+"') ORDER BY bank_name ASC");  
   while(rs.next()){
   buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(2)+"</option>";  
   }  
   }
  buffer=buffer+"</select>";  
  response.getWriter().println(buffer); 
 }
  catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
 }

%>

<html><body>
 <br><br><br>
<table width="900" border="1" style="top:250px; position:relative; ">
 <th>State</th><th>District</th><th>Bank Name</th><th>Branch Name</th>
 <%
  try
{
if(bank_code.equals("All"))
 {
java.sql.Connection con1;
 con1=null;
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con1 = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
 Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement(); 
  ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT states.State_Long,districts.District_Name,banks.bank_name,bankdetail.branch_name FROM bankdetail INNER JOIN states ON bankdetail.state_code=states.State_Code AND states.State_Code='"+state+"' INNER JOIN districts ON bankdetail.district_code=districts.District_Code AND districts.District_Code='"+district+"' INNER JOIN banks ON bankdetail.bank_code=banks.bank_code ");  
   while(rs1.next()){
   %>
   <tr style="text-align:center;" >
   <td><%out.print(rs1.getString(1));%></td>
   <td><%out.print(rs1.getString(2));%></td>
   <td><%out.print(rs1.getString(3));%></td>
    <td><%out.print(rs1.getString(4));%></td></tr>
    <%
    }
     }
     else
   {
   java.sql.Connection con1;
 con1=null;
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con1 = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");
  Statement stmt1 = con1.createStatement(); 
  ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT states.State_Long,districts.District_Name,banks.bank_name,bankdetail.branch_name FROM bankdetail INNER JOIN states ON bankdetail.state_code=states.State_Code AND states.State_Code='"+state+"' INNER JOIN districts ON bankdetail.district_code=districts.District_Code AND districts.District_Code='"+district+"' INNER JOIN banks ON bankdetail.bank_code=banks.bank_code AND banks.bank_code='"+bank_code+"'");  
   while(rs1.next()){
   %>
   <tr style="text-align:center;" >
   <td><%out.print(rs1.getString(1));%></td>
    <td><%out.print(rs1.getString(2));%></td>
   <td><%out.print(rs1.getString(3));%></td>
   <td><%out.print(rs1.getString(4));%></td></tr>
    <%
    }
    }
     }
   catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
 }

%>
</table></body></html>
```

these pages diplay the drop down data..and at last selection of bank table is displayed..
but the table contains duplicate entries in columns such as

```
                   state      district      bank       branch
                  punjab      bathinda      SBI          ABC
                  punjab      bathinda      SBI          PQR
                  punjab      bathinda      SBI          XYZ
```

but i want to elimnate that duplicacy..want the table like this....

```
                   state      district       bank       branch
                   punjab     bathinda       SBI         ABC
                                                         PQR
                                                         XYZ
```

kindly help me do that..thanku and also help me simplify this code...as m new to coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep track of the last value of the column and compare it to the new one. If it didn't change, suppress the value.  If it changed, show the value.  And set the last value to the new one at the end of the loop.

The .... here is where you would apply this to the other columns.

```
 String invalid_value = "some invalid value";
 String col1_old = invalid_value;
 .....
 while(rs1.next())
 {
    out.print("<tr style=\"text-align:center;\">");
    if(!col1_old.equals(rs1.getString(1)))
    {
          out.print("<td>"+rs1.getString(1)+"</td>");
    }
    else
    { 
           out.print("<td>&nbsp;</td>");
    }
    .....
     col1_old = rs1.getString(1);
    .....
    out.print("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: hey thanku for the it workes perfectly...there's problem that this code is working good with oracle database ans BEA weblogic...but the table rows r not being viewed using same code in tomcat using MS SQL database...kindly help

Comment: This code should work on any database type. It may be, however, that some don't let you do rs1.getString on fields that aren't strings.

Comment: but when comparing the rs1.getString(1) with col1_old...its not printing the VAlue of rs1.getString(1)..but printing everything else..even if hello or rs1.getString(2)or(3)or(4)..the error it is giving is no data found...but the query is working fine in SQL...kindly help...m unable to trace the error why this is happening

Comment: Try using the field names instead of going by numbers. It will make the code clearer anyway. rs.getString("field");